# Can XDomainRequest be used to load and draw images?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, xdomainrequest

I am loading in images from a server on a different domain. The images are CORS-enabled (they have this header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`). In modern browsers, using `image.crossOrigin = ''`, I am able to safely draw them to a `<canvas>`.

I would like to also be able to do the same on Internet Explorer 9. IE9 does not support `crossOrigin` on images. It does have `XDomainRequest` for cross-domain requests using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Is it possible to load a PNG via `XDomainRequest` and draw it to a canvas?

Answer (score 2):

**Complications of Downloading images with XDomainRequest in IE**

IE only allows XdomainRequest to work with plain-text data (ARGH!!):  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

IE will also sniff all incoming data using its `FindMimeFromData`.  So even if you strip off the url's type prefix (data:image/png;base64), this sniffer will realize that your base64 text is really an image and treat it accordingly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(v=vs.85).aspx

A possible try would be to re-encode the base64 text somehow to confuse the sniffer.

MS apparently realizes that their CORS policy is too restrictive and is planning on adding expanded CORS support to their webAPI:  http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/ASPNET-Web-API-and-CORS-Support

Otherwise you’re left with the current solution of bouncing images off your own web server so that they’re not X-domain anymore.